# Perl one line if statement

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have a statement

```
$set eq "Y" ? $set = "N" : $set = "Y";
```

But no matter what it always sets to `"N"`

```
# Toggle setting
if ($set eq "Y")
{
   $set = "N";
}
else
{
   $set = "Y";
}
```

Why doesn't the one liner seem to work?

Comment: @ruakh: Yes, but it doesn't change it from `'Y'` to `'N'`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, you're right. The OP said it always sets it to `'N'`, but actually the exact opposite is true.

Comment: Oh yes, this is true. I forgot I swapped the answers back to their original.

Comment: I'm sure this is just a simplified example, but in this case `$set = 'N' if $set eq 'Y';` is a bit easier to read, or even `$set =~ s/^Y$/N/;`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Due to precedence rules, perl is not parsing your statement as you think:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '$set eq "Y" ? $set = "N" : $set = "Y"'
((($set eq 'Y') ? ($set = 'N') : $set) = 'Y');
-e syntax OK
```

So as you see, in both conditions, the final result is the `$set` scalar which then gets set to `Y`.

You can fix it with a few parens:

```
$set eq "Y" ? $set = "N" : ($set = "Y")
```

But why repeat the assignment:

```
$set = $set eq 'Y' ? 'N' : 'Y';
```

Comment: Thanks, for the in-depth explanation as to my bad Perl. I ended up with a `my $set = ($set eq 'Y' ? 'N' : 'Y');` like in @Keith's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Operator precedence.  What you've written is equivalent to

```
($set eq "Y" ? $set = "N" : $set) = "Y";
```

If you insist on writing such terse code, this make more sense:

```
$set = ( $set eq "Y" ? "N" : "Y" );
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$set = ($set eq "Y") ? "N" : "Y";
```

should work

Answer (score 5):

It's about precedence; let's do the intent with parenthesis, and then let Perl remove them again:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e '($set eq "Y") ? ($set = "N") : ($set = "Y"); print $set'
$set eq 'Y' ? $set = 'N' : ($set = 'Y');
print $set;
-e syntax OK
```

Which is thus the parenthesing required to do as you intended.

Answer (score 4):

If you rather not use "C" style conditional statements, you can do the same thing with 2 lines:

```
my $set = "Y"; #Set the scope and default value
$set = "N" if ($set eq "Y");
```

I personally recommend the "C" style described by others above... it easily demonstrates the two options a variable can be.

However, the method I show is great when dealing with a single conditional result.